# Getting delimiter from a line

Tags: php, csv, substring, delimiter

Can someone please tell me the best possible way in PHP to find the non-whitespace delimiter from a given line?

Some examples are:

Ex 1:
    
`jon, doe, abc@gmail.com, 996655`

Ex 2:
    
`abc@gmail.com; doe; ;996655`

Ex 3:
    
`jon# doe# 996655# abc@gmail.com`

Ex 4:
    
`jon doe 96655`

Ex 5:
    
`jon doe 996655 abc@gmail.com`

Ex 6:
    
`jon;doe;abc@gmail.com;996655;`

In ex 4 and 5 above, it should return as no delimiter found.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How would that work? `o` or `a` may be equally valid as delimiters as other characters.

Comment: I think you may need to provide more details here. Do you know which language you're planning to use for this?

Comment: Are you able to use Regular Expressions?

Comment: Its in PHP and yes I think its not possible without using regular expression.

The idea is to get the next char (except white space) of the email address in a line as the delimiter. If the email is at the last column, it should get the previous char before the email (except white space). Once it finds that char, it should check if that char is NOT any of these a-zA-Z0-9.\r\n\f

Pls can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> If the email is at the last column, it should get the previous char before the email (except white space). Once it finds that char, it should check if that char is NOT any of these a-zA-Z0-9.\r\n\f

```
<?
//Store list
$list = "jon, doe, abc@gmail.com, 996655";
//Split list
$keywords = preg_split("/[:;,#]/", $list);
//Find the position of the last character of the matching word from the list
$index = strpos($list, $keywords[0]) + strlen($keywords[0]);
//Print it
echo substr($list, $index, 1);
?>
```